# Why does declaring a structure within a structure not work?

Tags: c, recursion, struct, declaration

Learning C recently and came across this problem

```
struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct c;
};

struct thisstruct { 
    int d;
    float e;

    struct myStruct c;
};
```

'struct thisStruct c;' returns an error, but not 'struct myStruct c;'. Why is this so?

Comment: Don't you get "`field 'c' has incomplete type`" for `struct thisStruct c;`? The answer is that you can't have `struct`s with unknown size and your setup makes it hard for the compiler to figure that out.

Comment: recursive structs.... nice ;-)

Comment: When the compiler sees the line `struct thisStruct c;` it has no idea what `struct thisStruct` is so the code can't compile. You need to move the definition of `struct thisStruct` to before `struct myStruct`. When you do that you'll instead get a problem with `struct myStruct c;` and you have to the definition of `struct myStruct` to before `struct thisStruct` but then you have to move the defintion of .... It's going to be a long afternoon. ;-)  (in short: what you are trying to do is of cause impossible)

Comment: Also note that the compiler is case sensitive. `thisStruct != thisstruct`

Comment: @TedLyngmo nice catch... then it isn't recursive structs after all...

Comment: One may turn this around and ask OP: What would you expect if this had compiled? `myStruct` contains a `thisStruct` that contains a `myStruct` that contains a `thisStruct` that contains a ...  ... for all eternity.

Comment: `thisstruct ` vs `thisStruct `? Please tell us if it is a typo or if it is on purpose. If it's on purpose then be aware that distinguishing identifiers by the sole difference of one letter having a different case is very bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

For starters there is a typo in the presented code snippet.

```
struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct c;
};

struct thisstruct { 
    int d;
    float e;

    struct myStruct c;
};
```

It seems you mean that the second declaration declares a structure with the name `thisStruct` instead of the name `thisstruct`.

As for your question then according to the C Standard (6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers)

> 3 **A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or
> function type** (hence, a structure shall not contain an instance of
> itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance of itself), except
> that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
> may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union
> containing, possibly recursively, a member that is such a structure)
> shall not be a member of a structure or an element of an array

In this structure declaration

```
struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct c;
};
```

the type `struct thisStruct` is an incomplete type. Its size is unknown. You may declare a pointer of this structure type like

```
struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct *c;
};
```

because pointer types are always complete types. Their sizes are known.

Otherwise in these declarations

```
struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct c;
};

struct thisStruct { 
    int d;
    float e;

    struct myStruct c;
};
```

you have an infinite recursion. That is the definition of the data member

```
struct thisStruct c;
```

includes the definition of the structure `thisStruct` that in turn again includes the definition of the structure `myStruct` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This C code too, like every other C code, can be regarded as parsed from top to bottom. Therefore at the point where you declare `struct thisStruct c`, the compiler has no idea what that type is, because it has not yet seen that struct definition.

You could declare *pointers* to structs before the compiler knows what those structs are, by *forward declaring* the struct:

```
struct thisStruct;

struct myStruct { 
    int a;
    float b;

    struct thisStruct* c;
};
```

However, this means you have to use pointers.

That being said, a program design of some X containing an Y containing an X is very likely nonsense. I very much doubt there exists a valid scenario where you would need that. Reconsider your design.

Comment: "I very much doubt there exists a valid scenario where you would need that." I very much doubt that a computer with sufficient memory for this use case has been build.

Comment: @4386427 Assuming they both are pointer members, then it doesn't take any memory worth mentioning. But it's likely senseless design still.

Comment: True, true... But if they are pointer members, it's not a situation where " X containing an Y containing an X ..."

Answer (score 0):

As the C compiler does not know the size of the struct or union which was not yet declared it cant place such a struct or union inside other data structure. Only **pointer** (as size of pointer is known to the compiler) to not yet declared structure or union can be used.